# Are Product Recommendation questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, close-reasons

Most SE sites I participate in have sections in the help documentation and close options to make "product recommendations" off topic for the site. These sorts of questions are often opinion based and attract spam (vendor X is best). However I'm not seeing this for DevOps. Does this mean they are on topic here or should we update the help pages to explicitly state they are off topic?

Comment: For reference, the original blog post explaining why it's explicitly off-topic on most sites: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell we don't have a fixed policy, some questions may have definitive answers ("Which product may I use for configuration management on a sshless machines ?" for exemple have a closed list of tools allowing that and the answer would probably stay limited), "Which tools should I use for CI/CD?" however would be far too large and mostly opinion based and closed as such.

So for now, we don't close product recommendation as that because the spam problem has not been a problem here, we may change that if the case arise and gets out of control.